# Can OP see the list of users who voted for deletion on their question?

Tags: feature-request, voting, deleted-questions, vote-to-delete, timeline

My question is simple: is it possible for OP to see the list of users who voted for deleting their question in the question's timeline?

If [this answer](https://meta.stackoverflow.com/a/408467/17949945) is still correct, the  OP can see the names of close-voters even if they have less then 3,000 reputation.

So I wonder if a question author with reputation **under** 10,000 can in a similar way find out the names of those who have cast delete votes? (*same about answer-authors under 10,000 if there were any answers*)

### Rational behind the Question

If the answer is yes, maybe it would be wise not to disclose this information.

I can't know if my deletion votes had any impact on the actions of the Authors of the deleted post. But I know for sure from close-voting experience that people might get angry when their Question has been closed.

I often leave a comment explaining the issues, while closing a question, especially when no one have done it yet. And several times I've received an emotionally charged reply from angry users (just because my comment was there).

Therefore, I'm convinced that detailed information about voters should be hidden from the users that haven't yet received a right to vote. Because their judgement regarding the quality/uniqueness of a particular Question would more likely deviate from the Community standards.

And situations when such users are unhappy about their question being unfairly closed/removed and seeking for retaliation against close/delete voters are more likely to happen.

Comment: Yes, that information is even visible on the post (deletion) notice. A <10K user doesn't even need to check the timeline to find that out.

Comment: I personally think that removing it from the post notice and keeping it in the post's timeline/revisions is fine (at least for consistency with close voters). If you disagree, you should probably edit the question and explain why you think the list of delete voters should be completely hidden while the list of close voters is kept visible for those who know where to look.

Comment: "If the answer is yes, maybe it would be wise not to disclose this information" - since the answer is "Yes" indeed, this is a feature request and it was already asked before, i.e. a duplicate.

Comment: In the past this wasn't much of a problem, as the way to find your deleted posts was quite well hidden. Now that that information is more public (You can see all your deleted content, not just the content that was recently deleted), and more discoverable, it might be wise to update the existing FR with why this might be a bigger problem now, then it was back when the FR was first proposed.